# Is there an ambiguity in the definition of the limit that allows convergence to multiple values?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I was trying to understand the definition of the limit since it's literally the bedrock of Calculus. The typical idea of convergence is that for some limiting value $L$, the value of a function can always be as close to $L$ as we want. The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition states that there can only be a single limiting value (somewhat implicitly). In the case of something like a jump discontinuity, the limit doesn’t exist.

Suppose we have a function $f(x)$ that’s differentiable everywhere and that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$. Consider the typical setup for this limit but with one addition: for any $\epsilon\gt0$ let $$0\lt\xi\lt\epsilon$$ Note that since $\xi\gt0$, $L\neq L+\xi$. I get that the limit has been defined to only have a single limiting value, but the definition seems to have an ambiguity.

Doesn't the limit converge to both $L$ and $L+\xi$ since we can always choose a $\xi<\epsilon$ in the limiting process?

Comment: Not in the real line, metric spaces or Hausdorff spaces (given $x\neq y$, there are open neighborhoods of $U$ and $V$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$) for that matter. There are *pathological spaces* where points do not separate where ambiguity happens, but this may be still not within your grasp yet. You may search for Hausdorff spaces on Wikipedia just out of curiosity.

Comment: Looking at examples is a good approach if you think you have discovered an exception to a well-known mathematical result. In this case, just look at the limit of $f(x) = x$ as $x \to 0$: you don't have the option to choose $\xi \neq 0$ (your $\xi$ has to have $|\xi| < \varepsilon$ for every positive $\varepsilon$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree that "The $\varepsilon$−$\delta$ definition states that there can only be a single limiting value (somewhat implicitly)." However we can prove that the limit is unique. Suppose that $L$ and $M$ are both limits of $f$ as $x\to a$. Then for each $\varepsilon$ we can choose a $\delta$ such that both $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon/2$ and $|f(x)-M|<\varepsilon/2$. By the triangle inequality we now get $|L-M|\leq |f(x)-L|+|f(x)-M|<\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon$. So what we have proved is that the real number $|L-M|$ is less than any $\varepsilon$. The only such real number is $0$ so $|L-M|=0$ and $L=M$.

Now, the problem with your proof that $f$ converges to both $L$ and $L+\xi$ is that you are changing the real number after we give you an $\varepsilon$. What I'm trying to say is that for $f$ to approach a real number $L$, you have to specify that $L$ and then choose a $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$. You cannot keep changing your $L$.

Also, for a limit of a function to exist, it does not need to be differentiable, but only continuous. If it is differentiable however, it is also continuous.

Comment: I like your explanation in simple language +1

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was very easy to understand! It seems like what I did was just state that we could find some value between L and L + ε given any ε, just with more symbols. I was no longer talking about a limiting value. I also assumed the reals aren’t well-ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Your $\xi$ depends on $\epsilon$ so it makes no sense to say the limit is $L + \xi$.

If there were two limits $L - M > 0$ then with $\epsilon = (L-M)/3$ you could not find a $\delta$ since the function would have to be within $\epsilon$ of both $L$ and $M$.